# Multiple actions in a single Query in MS_Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is it possible for me to do multiple actions in a single query or do I have to make a query for every change I would like to make?

I have a Column "Type"  wich can have the string values "BOOL", "WORD" or "DINT"

In one single query, I would like to:

- change all the "BOOL" into "DIGITAL"
- change all the "WORD" into "UINT"
- change all the "DINT" into "LONG"

Is it possible to do this in 1 single query (if yes, how?)

OR do i have to make several queries like this:

```
UPDATE DB_Total SET Type = 'DIGITAL'
WHERE Type='BOOL';
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `Switch()` as an alternative to nested `IIf()` expressions.

With this data in `DB_Total` ...

```sql
id Type
 1 BOOL
 2 abc
 3        <-- Type is Null
 4 WORD
 5 DINT
```

... this query updates `DB_Total` as shown below ...

```sql
UPDATE DB_Total
SET [Type] = Switch(
    [Type]='BOOL','DIGITAL',
    [Type]='WORD','UINT',
    [Type]='DINT','LONG'
    )
WHERE [Type] IN ('BOOL', 'WORD', 'DINT');
```

`DB_Total` after:

```sql
id Type
 1 DIGITAL
 2 abc
 3 
 4 UINT
 5 LONG
```

However you may find a different approach more convenient.  Create a `replacements` table:

```sql
id old_type new_type
 1 BOOL     DIGITAL
 2 WORD     UINT
 3 DINT     LONG
```

Then this `UPDATE` statement will produce the same changes to `DB_Total` as the `Switch()` version.

```sql
UPDATE DB_Total AS d
INNER JOIN replacements AS r
ON d.Type = r.old_type
SET d.Type = [r].[new_type];
```

In the future, if you need to change or add/remove pairs of word replacements, you would only need to edit the `replacements` table.  You would then not need to revise the query.

Comment: Ah yes! that replace statement makes the code much better to change if needed, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Nested `IIF` statement:

```
UPDATE  DB_Total
SET     Type = IIF(Type='BOOL','DIGITAL',
                    IIF(Type='WORD','UINT',
                        IIF(Type='DINT','LONG',Type)
                    )
                )
WHERE   Type IN ('BOOL', 'WORD', 'DINT');
```

*(I'd usually write the IIF part all on one line, but I've done line breaks just so it is easier to read)*

Comment: Oh awesome! after Naresh's response i almost gave up all hope :P